# Highcharts: how to get the point category clicked on when drilling down?

Tags: jquery, highcharts, drilldown

Using the default example of Highcharts for [columns with drilldown](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/), I am trying to get the category clicked on when drilling down.

For instance, clicking on the "Chrome" column, should alert "Chrome"

I have added an event on click, but on drilldown, i receive a null, and when drilling up, i receive the category index.

What am I missing? My example is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/krawLLvy/)

```js
$(function () {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }

        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                },
                
                point: {
          events: {
            click: function(event) {
              alert(this.category);
            }
          }
        }
                
                
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                y: 56.33,
                drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 24.03,
                drilldown: 'Chrome'
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 10.38,
                drilldown: 'Firefox'
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                y: 4.77,
                drilldown: 'Safari'
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                y: 0.91,
                drilldown: 'Opera'
            }, {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2,
                drilldown: null
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v11.0',
                        24.13
                    ],
                    [
                        'v8.0',
                        17.2
                    ],
                    [
                        'v9.0',
                        8.11
                    ],
                    [
                        'v10.0',
                        5.33
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.0',
                        1.06
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.0',
                        0.5
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                id: 'Chrome',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v40.0',
                        5
                    ],
                    [
                        'v41.0',
                        4.32
                    ],
                    [
                        'v42.0',
                        3.68
                    ],
                    [
                        'v39.0',
                        2.96
                    ],
                    [
                        'v36.0',
                        2.53
                    ],
                    [
                        'v43.0',
                        1.45
                    ],
                    [
                        'v31.0',
                        1.24
                    ],
                    [
                        'v35.0',
                        0.85
                    ],
                    [
                        'v38.0',
                        0.6
                    ],
                    [
                        'v32.0',
                        0.55
                    ],
                    [
                        'v37.0',
                        0.38
                    ],
                    [
                        'v33.0',
                        0.19
                    ],
                    [
                        'v34.0',
                        0.14
                    ],
                    [
                        'v30.0',
                        0.14
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                id: 'Firefox',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v35',
                        2.76
                    ],
                    [
                        'v36',
                        2.32
                    ],
                    [
                        'v37',
                        2.31
                    ],
                    [
                        'v34',
                        1.27
                    ],
                    [
                        'v38',
                        1.02
                    ],
                    [
                        'v31',
                        0.33
                    ],
                    [
                        'v33',
                        0.22
                    ],
                    [
                        'v32',
                        0.15
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                id: 'Safari',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v8.0',
                        2.56
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.1',
                        0.77
                    ],
                    [
                        'v5.1',
                        0.42
                    ],
                    [
                        'v5.0',
                        0.3
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.1',
                        0.29
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.0',
                        0.26
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.2',
                        0.17
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                id: 'Opera',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v12.x',
                        0.34
                    ],
                    [
                        'v28',
                        0.24
                    ],
                    [
                        'v27',
                        0.17
                    ],
                    [
                        'v29',
                        0.16
                    ]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move your action to the [`chart.events.drilldown`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown) like so:

```
chart: {
  type: 'column',
  events: {
    drilldown: function(e) {
                alert(e.seriesOptions.name);
            }
  }
},
```

This would work on clicking the point or the xAxis category label.

Comment: Thanks! i missed this one in the documentation